# how to implement a hint text with white spaces in android

Tags: java, android, android-layout, layout

I want to implement a editText with blanks like this:

[image]

I have thought of some options,

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/verificationCodeEditText"
    style="@style/textOnBg"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:text="-   -   -   -"
    android:textColor="#00bcfe"
    android:textSize="16dp"
    android:textStyle="italic" >
</EditText>
```

1) using a hint= "- - - -" and then the user just override the hint.

The problem is how to skip the white spaces so the user won't override them

2) using a textChangeWatcher and move the selector to the next non-blank char

```
private void initTextWatcher() {
    mTextWatcher = new TextWatcher() {
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            mCodeEditText.setSelection(s.length());
        }

        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {
        }

        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                int count) {
            mCodeEditText.removeTextChangedListener(mTextWatcher);
            mCodeEditText.setText(mCodeEditText.getText().toString()
                    .replace('-', s.charAt(start)));
            mCodeEditText.addTextChangedListener(mTextWatcher);
        }
    };
    mCodeEditText.addTextChangedListener(mTextWatcher);
}
```

3) other built in way?

which one do you think is preferable?

Answer (score 0):

Why to use single edit text. You can use 4 edit text views.